# Transpose variables in SQL Server using a lookup table

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple databases (dev, qa, production) which contain the same data but with different id's. In these databases formulas are stored where references are made to these id's. I want to be able to migrate the formulas from dev to qa or from qa to production and want to keep the logic of the formula but transpose the id's to match the id's in the destination table.

The formulas are stored as text and this is an example of a formula:

```
$PD_2:A55_K763_A_N_I,A55_K764_A_N_I,A55_K762_A_N_I,A55_K761_A_N_I
```

The id's that need translation start with an A or a K (based on the type) and end with an underscore.

I can easily create a translation table (or view) which would store the source_id and target_id.

Right now this translation table would contain +- 1000 items, but the solution should be able to handle 100K minimum.

My question is: what would be the best way to transpose these formulas?

Update 1:
Some sample data can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f867d/1/0

Update 2:

The approach I am thinking off is:

1. Insert formulas into temporary table
2. Update all variables so that we can easily identify them as not yet transposed (i.e. A55 => {A55}) => My idea would be to this with a RegEx
3. Translate all variables => My idea would be to this with either a CTE or a cursor

I am not sure how to start.

Comment: It would be better to have consistent id's (keys) across the databases rather than modify the formula on each database. If this can't be done please add reasons for why you can't do this and add a bit of sample data.

Comment: Hi @Tanner, thanks for your reply. The id fields are incrementing ints, new id's can be created in production and dev. Here we loose the consistency.  I updated my request with sample data.